# Getting module and version from a file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file (text.txt) which contain the following lines:

```
|**tashtit.liba.version**|2001.01.2012072137|
|**tashtit.gimla.version**|2001.01.2012072156|
|**chaluka.version**|2001.01.2012080754|
|**analytics.version**|2001.01.2012072142|
|**yizumim.version**|2001.01.2012072222|
```

I would like the following output (text2.txt):

```
tashtit.liba-2001.01.2012072137
tashtit.gimla-2001.01.2012072156
chaluka-2001.01.2012080754
analytics-2001.01.2012072142
yizumim-2001.01.2012072222
```

How can i get that using bash and some regex?
The above is example and the answer should fit the following convention:
`|**${module}.version**|$version|`

Comment: So, you basically want to replace `|**` by nothing and `.version**|` by hyphen?

Comment: correct + remove the last pipeline

Comment: So, what's the question? You can use `sed`. Or do you want it in bash itself? Why?

Comment: sed is also good, just didn't figure it out, what is your suggestion?

Comment: what @eewanco suggested more or less

Comment: I didn't downvote you but some people want to see what your attempts to solve the problem have been. They want to see a modicum of effort to solve the problem yourself. Me, I don't care so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/|\*\*\([a-z.]*\)\.version\*\*|\([0-9.]*\)|/\1-\2/1'
```

This matches a literal `|**` followed by a grouping of lowercase letters and periods terminated by a literal `.version**|`, then another grouping of numbers and periods terminated by `|`, with the first grouping, a hyphen, and the second grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -rn 's/(^\|\*\*)(.*)(.version)(\*\*\|)(.*)(\|$)/\3-\5/p' file
```

Split each line into 5 sections base don regular expressions. Substitute the line for the 2nd and 4th sections, separated by "-" using sed and print.

Awk alternative:

```
awk -F\| '{ $0=gensub("*","","g",$0);split($2,map,".");print map[1]"-"$3 }' file
```

Set the field delimiter to | and then then strip any asterix out of the lines and further split the 3rd delimited field with ".". Print the 2nd and 3th | delimited fields.

Comment: the output still contains the `.version` - but thanks a lot :-)